# How to compare two arrays and find the optimal match in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

I have two arrays X and Y, X is the base array and Y is operated in a loop. As the loop runs I want to compare the arrays to find the nearest value of Y to X or in other words where is Y most close to X. As an example I have attached the reproducible code:

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import interpolate


x = np.array([[0.12, 0.11, 0.1, 0.09, 0.08],
       [0.13, 0.12, 0.11, 0.1, 0.09],
       [0.15, 0.14, 0.12, 0.11, 0.1],
       [0.17, 0.15, 0.14, 0.12, 0.11],
       [0.19, 0.17, 0.16, 0.14, 0.12],
       [0.22, 0.19, 0.17, 0.15, 0.13],
       [0.24, 0.22, 0.19, 0.16, 0.14],
       [0.27, 0.24, 0.21, 0.18, 0.15],
       [0.29, 0.26, 0.22, 0.19, 0.16]])

y = np.array([[0.07, 0.06, 0.05, 0.04, 0.03],
              [0.08, 0.07, 0.06, 0.05, 0.04],
              [0.10, 0.09, 0.07, 0.06, 0.05],
              [0.14, 0.12, 0.11, 0.09, 0.08],
              [0.16, 0.14, 0.13, 0.11, 0.09],
              [0.19, 0.16, 0.14, 0.12, 0.10],
              [0.22, 0.20, 0.17, 0.14, 0.12],
              [0.25, 0.22, 0.19, 0.16, 0.13],
              [0.27, 0.24, 0.20, 0.17, 0.14]])


for i in range(100):
    y = y + (i / 10000)
```

I want to break the loop when the closest values have been found. *By closest I mean, the values should be within ±10% of the original values or some other percentage.* How can this be done in Python?

Comment: define `optimal match` and `most close` terms. People use different approaches to measure closeness of matrices (arrays).

Comment: Maximize coefficient of determination, maybe

Comment: Please update your question with this clarification

Comment: Don't forget to divide `i` by a float in the `for` loop to increment `y` (`y = y + (i / 10000.)`)

Comment: Please correct the y increment for consistency (see comment above)

Comment: @bougui  I have imported division from __future__.

Answer (score 3):

You can compute the Euclidean distance between the two matrices:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.spatial.distance
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.array([[0.12, 0.11, 0.1, 0.09, 0.08],
   [0.13, 0.12, 0.11, 0.1, 0.09],
   [0.15, 0.14, 0.12, 0.11, 0.1],
   [0.17, 0.15, 0.14, 0.12, 0.11],
   [0.19, 0.17, 0.16, 0.14, 0.12],
   [0.22, 0.19, 0.17, 0.15, 0.13],
   [0.24, 0.22, 0.19, 0.16, 0.14],
   [0.27, 0.24, 0.21, 0.18, 0.15],
   [0.29, 0.26, 0.22, 0.19, 0.16]])
y = np.array([[0.07, 0.06, 0.05, 0.04, 0.03],
          [0.08, 0.07, 0.06, 0.05, 0.04],
          [0.10, 0.09, 0.07, 0.06, 0.05],
          [0.14, 0.12, 0.11, 0.09, 0.08],
          [0.16, 0.14, 0.13, 0.11, 0.09],
          [0.19, 0.16, 0.14, 0.12, 0.10],
          [0.22, 0.20, 0.17, 0.14, 0.12],
          [0.25, 0.22, 0.19, 0.16, 0.13],
          [0.27, 0.24, 0.20, 0.17, 0.14]])

dists = []
for i in range(100):
     y = y + (i / 10000.)
     dists.append(scipy.spatial.distance.euclidean(x.flatten(), y.flatten()))
plt.plot(dists)
```

will return this graph, which is the evolution of the Euclidean distance between your 2 matrices:
[image]

To break the loop at the minimum, you can use:

```
dist = np.inf
for i in range(100):
    y = y + (i / 10000.)
    d = scipy.spatial.distance.euclidean(x.flatten(), y.flatten())
    if d < dist:
        dist = d
    else:
        break
print dist
# 0.0838525491562 #(the minimal distance)
print y
#[[ 0.1051  0.0951  0.0851  0.0751  0.0651] 
#[ 0.1151  0.1051  0.0951  0.0851  0.0751] 
#[ 0.1351  0.1251  0.1051  0.0951  0.0851] 
#[ 0.1751  0.1551  0.1451  0.1251  0.1151] 
#[ 0.1951  0.1751  0.1651  0.1451  0.1251] 
#[ 0.2251  0.1951  0.1751  0.1551  0.1351] 
#[ 0.2551  0.2351  0.2051  0.1751  0.1551] 
#[ 0.2851  0.2551  0.2251  0.1951  0.1651] 
#[ 0.3051  0.2751  0.2351  0.2051  0.1751]]
```

Comment: Actually you can use a lot of different metrics: see http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/spatial.distance.html